# Programmatically change Image Source inside of button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am attempting to change the source of an image control inside of a button but am struggling to get it to work without an exception occuring. This is what I have so far

XAML

```
<Grid Height="33" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <Button x:Name="btnAttendance" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#FF1D2531" Foreground="#FFB7C0CD" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="20,1,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Click="button_SidebarClick" Style="{StaticResource STY_SidebarPrimary}" FontFamily="Source Sans Pro Semibold">
          <Button.ContentTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                         <Image x:Name="imgAttendance" Source="Resources/IMG_LinkFull.png" Height="33" Width="Auto" Margin="23.5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                         <TextBlock Margin="23,0,0,0" Width="Auto" FontFamily="Source Sans Pro Semibold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF838990"><Run Text="Attendance"/></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
          </Button.ContentTemplate>
     </Button>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
 ControlTemplate ct = btnAttendance.Template;
 Image btnImage = (Image)ct.FindName("imgAttendance", btnAttendance);
 btnImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/IMG_LinkFull_Active.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Any idea where I am going wrong? I tried to reference the image file directly but the control is not visible/accessible.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: `btnAttendance.Template` gives you the Button's `Template`, not its `ContentTemplate`. These are two different things.

Comment: Can you try by loading the simple textblock with contents inside the template ? If it works, then the Image source is not sets correctly. Please ignore if already tried this.

Comment: Thank you for the help and suggestions! It was indeed the ContentTemplate, since I was messing with other uses before I never realized I needed to remove that to still implement the image source change.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
                    Image image = new Image();
                    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"msappx:///Resources/IMG_LinkFull_Active.png"));
                    myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
                    btnAttendance.Background = myBrush;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eli was correct about removing the ContentTemplate. The following code is what achieved the image source change..

```
imgAttendance.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/IMG_LinkFull_Active.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```